# Ideal data type for currency rate in MySQL

Tags: mysql, decimal, sqldatatypes

What should I ideally use to store currency rate information in my MySQL database? Should I use:

- double
- decimal like (10,4)
- float or
- something else?

Currency rates are usually decimal numbers like 1.2362.

Comment: Might be opinion based, but it should be Decimal or Integer with number of digits stored separatly

Comment: Yeah I want to hear opinions :-), thanks

Answer (score 4):

How precise do you need to be?  I ask because the problem may go beyond the storage format of the conversion factor.  For example, perhaps the rules might be to keep the factor to N decimal places, perform the multiplication (or division) to M places, then round.  And the "round" might be "financial" -- 0.5 always rounds up, instead of IEEE-754, "round to nearest even".

Assuming you can afford to be off by one unit in the last place (cents or centimes or whatever), I would simply use `DOUBLE`.

I assume you won't be storing more than, say, 100 conversion factors, so the fact that `DOUBLE` occupies 8 bytes will not be an issue.  If you are recording the conversion factors for every minute for the past 10 years, I would rethink this decision.

`FLOAT` gives you 6-7 *significant* digits (and takes 4 bytes); `DOUBLE` gives about 16.  `12345` and `123.45` and `0.00012345` each have 5 "significant" digits.

For currency, itself, I think the maximum number of *decimal places* for any currency today is 4.  That is, `DECIMAL(nn, 4)` should suffice for storing money.

However, that does not provide the necessary rounding.

```
ROUND(currency1 * factor, decimals)
```

where `decimals` is 2 for a target currency of USD and Euros (and many other currencies).  As I pointed out above, this may differ from what a bank would compute by as much as one cent.

(Would you call this "opinion based"?  Or something better?)

Comment: I will keep up to 4 decimal places. That's how our bank servers us currency rates. For example: 1.2450. I went with DECIMAL(10,4). I like your answer.